# AD Passthrough authentication failing on Synapse Analytics Serverless Pool

Tags: serverless, azure-synapse

This is regarding the access issue that I am facing in reading the data residing in ADLS Gen-2 from Synapse Analytics Serverless Pool.

1. I have full access on Synapse Studio
2. I have "Storage Blob Data Contributor" on the container/folder where my parquet file is residing

While I try to below SQL ( with right ADLS name along with folder/container details)

SELECT
TOP 100 *
FROM
OPENROWSET(
BULK 'https://.dfs.core.windows.net/<container_name>////2009/DIM_INFO_2009.parquet',
FORMAT='PARQUET'
) AS [result]

I get below message -

File 'https://.dfs.core.windows.net/<container_name>////2009/DIM_INFO_2009.parquet' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.

When I try the same scenario by creating the external table ( which points to the same parquet file) and uses MANAGED IDENTITY as credentials - the results are being displayed as expected.

So - I am wondering, what is causing this issue - when I try to run the SQL and make the results get displayed. I was hoping with having Storage Blob Data Contributor - it should allow me to access the data on ADLS from Synapse Studio Serverless Pool.

Any hints on what might be causing this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AAD passthrough auth make sure you also follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=user-identity&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762#configuration-via-powershell) to allow Synapse Serverless to get past the ADLS firewall with an identity other than the MSI.

If the PowerShell approach above doesn’t appeal to you then it is also [now available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762#grant-access-from-azure-resource-instances-preview) in the Azure Portal UI.

Comment: This issue has re-occured to me again , which was working few days before after following the steps Greg has listed above. exact same error message as earlier
Started executing query at Line 1

File 'https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.snappy.parquet' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.
Visit this article to learn more about this error
Total execution time: 00:00:01.999

I still have Storage Data Contributor access and I see in Azure portal , on storage account the resource instance has the properties set as mentioned above.